# Mockup Dimensions

Tags: mockup

I'm currently mocking up a site for a phone.

When I do a screengrab on my phone the size is 1080 x 1920 px.

If I'm only concerned with designing for this phone is it safe to mock with those dimensions?

If so why do so many recommend 768? This is a Galaxy 7, a very common phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because when people are designing responsive for web, a common media query (@media) is 768px. https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to mock for those dimensions 1080 x 1920 px if that is the ended device to be used for. Like Harley said 768px is a common media query but you don't necessarily have to follow that if you don't want. It's also convenient to do 1080 x 1920 px for high resolution monitors. You could also set the website to change based on the current resolution.